# Asignar Valores aleatorios en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Saludos hoy acudo a ustedes debido a que necesito asignar valores aleatorios en una tabla en SQL Server pero estos solo pueden varian entre (4,10,18) es decir solo pueden asignarse esos valores. he buscado y he encontrado la funcion "rand()" pero con esta funcion solo puedo obtener valores dentro de un rango pero no entre solo estos tres numeros, agradecería mucho su ayuda

Comment: Esto es una forma sencilla de hacerlo: `SELECT TOP 1 Valor
FROM (VALUES(4),(10),(18)) AS T(Valor)
ORDER BY NEWID();`

Comment: Qué es "Values" según tu comentario?

Comment: @CamiloBernal [Table Value Constructor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-specifying-multiple-values-as-a-derived-table-in-a-from-clause)

Comment: @Lamak, genial, no lo conocía!!! cómo aprende uno por estos lados jejeje. Gracias. Deberías colocarlo como respuesta al OP, es una gran alternativa.

Comment: @CamiloBernal Puedes agregarlo a tu respuesta sin problema. Actualmente no estoy posteando respuestas en ningún sitio de SE, pero no pude evitar darle una solución al op

Answer (score 3):

Considera el siguiente `query`:

```
declare @ValoresPosibles table (
  [value] INT
)

INSERT INTO @ValoresPosibles ([value]) VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO @ValoresPosibles ([value]) VALUES (10);
INSERT INTO @ValoresPosibles ([value]) VALUES (18);


select top 1 [value] from @ValoresPosibles ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Básicamente lo que hice fue crear una tabla temporal de tipo variable con los posibles valores, luego hacer un select con `top 1`ordenado por NewId (Una función randomica que "hace la magia").

Answer (score 3):

La solución de Lamak y Camilo es super elegante, pero otra alternativa es aprovechando `RAND` pero "randomizando" el valor de la fila a obtener, `CEILING(RAND()*<cantidad de posibilidades>)`, ejemplo:

```
SELECT  Valor 
    FROM (VALUES(4,1),(10,2),(18,3)) AS T(Valor, ID)
    WHERE ID = CEILING(RAND()*3)
```

Agrego la observación de Luis al respecto que la capacidad de generación de los valores aleatorios de este código esta limitado a un valor único por ejecución.

Comment: El problema es que ese RAND va a regresar el mismo valor en todas las filas.

Comment: Hola @LuisCazares, ¿a qué te refieres?

Comment: Al agregar el código a una consulta, el valor siempre será el mismo. Ejemplo: `SELECT object_id, Valor FROM sys.objects CROSS JOIN( SELECT  Valor  FROM (VALUES(4,1),(10,2),(18,3)) AS T(Valor, ID) WHERE ID = CEILING(RAND()*3))x`

Comment: Ok @LuisCazares, ahora sí, es buena tu aclaración